# Elisp to define a Ackermann's function

Tags: elisp

I am reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#footnote_Temp_48) and refer to its
`Exercise 1.10.  The following procedure computes a mathematical function called Ackermann's function.`

```
(define (A x y)
  (cond ((= y 0) 0)
        ((= x 0) (* 2 y))
        ((= y 1) 2)
        (else (A (- x 1)
                 (A x (- y 1))))))
```

Rewrite it with elisp

```
(defun A (x y)
  (cond ((= y 0) 0)
        ((= x 0) (* 2 y))
        ((= y 1) 2)
        (else (A (- x 1)
                 (A x (- y 1))))))

(A 1 10)
```

Report error:
`A: Symbol’s value as variable is void: else`

Refer to elisp's control structure thus lost in various alternatives.

Could you please provide hints to define that function with `cond` and `else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Emacs Lisp you use `t` instead of `else`. In cases like this, *Language Reference* is a good place to begin research... https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html:

> Often we want to execute the last clause whenever none of the previous
>   clauses was successful. To do this, we use `t` as the condition of the
>   last clause, like this: `(t body-forms)`. The form `t` evaluates to `t`,
>   which is never `nil`, so this clause never fails, provided the `cond` gets
>   to it at all. For example:
>
> ```
> (setq a 5)
> (cond ((eq a 'hack) 'foo)
>       (t "default"))
> ⇒ "default"
> ```